# Android / Eclipse: How to automate the export of a signed application package

Tags: android, eclipse, automation

Currently I'm developing an android application with some bluetooth functionality. So I have to export the app to a signed package and install it on a real device for testing.

Is it possible to automate the export of the project as a signed application package and then install it to the connected device?

(tiggered by a toolbar button in eclipse for example)

For the installation part I thougt about using the android-debug-bridge in the comand prompt:

```
adb install <path_to_apk>
```

But how to automate the signed export?

Comment: Why do you need to export a release version just for testing?

Comment: @Squonk one scenario would be to check if proguard works or not(proguard is only enabled in signed export mode and not in debug mode).

Comment: @afterburner : Yep, I understand exporting apps and using Proguard. I published my first app when Google Play was still called Android Market over 2 years ago. I've got two apps out there and also one of them is on Amazon Appstore. In reality, Proguard isn't a 100% guarantee against somebody reverse-engineering your code. The point of my question was why would anybody waste the time it takes to export an app just to test it on a real device. Proguard either works or it doesn't - if you're Alpha or Beta testing it makes no sense to bother with it.

Comment: Then the problem is a different. I read every app has to be signed to install it. And if I export a signed package and try to install it on my phone, an error message appears: "Application not installed".